# "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal" error when I convert to decimal

Tags: c#

Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal error is displaying when i convert to decimal code is below.

```
decimal tempValues = 0;
Value1 = 0.0
Value2 = 0.0
tempValues = Convert.ToDecimal(Value1 / Value2);
```

Can you help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't do zero divided by zero on a calculator why would you be able to do it in code?

Comment: @Liath He just divided by zero (by positive `0.0` to be precise) without problems. The trouble didn't arise until he tried to convert the quotient into another type,

Answer (score 6):

The text is a bit confusing. A more precise message would be *The value `NaN` cannot be converted to `Decimal` since the type does not support it*.

With `Double`, calculations never raise exceptions, but you may end up with values such as `PositiveInfinity`, `NegativeInfinity` and (like in this case) `NaN` (which means "not-a-number"). These values are not supported in `Decimal`.

Also, `Double` can represent some huge values, like `1E+50` (a figure `1` followed by 50 `0` digits), that are too big for the `Decimal` struct.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to resolve?
- You can't devide by 0.
- Double will show NaN that you can't convert to Decimal
- Decimals will throw DevideByZero Exception "Attempted to divide by zero."

```
 decimal tempValues = 0;
 decimal Value1 = 0.0m;
 decimal Value2 = 0.0m;
 tempValues = Value1 / Value2;
```